# Directing ADO queries away from the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado, middleware

I've got a large number of old Delphi apps accessing a remote SQL Server database using ADO. I would like to get direct those queries to a middleware layer instead of said database. The Delphi clients must run unchanged; I am not the owner of most of them.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how should I go about it?

Don't worry about parsing the T-SQL (both raw T-SQL and stored proc calls, incidentally).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new SQL database, and use a combination of views, T-SQL and managed code to fake up enough database objects for the application to work.

Technique 1: Use tables, but populate them asyncrhonously from the new data source.

Technique 2: Fake the tables and procedures

E.g. you can have a stored procedure which calls managed code to your middleware, to replace the existing stored procedure.

Where the application reads directly from a table, you can use a view, which references a managed table-valued function.

-

You should have no trouble wherever stored procedures are used. If the application sends dynamic SQL you have more of an uphill struggle however.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Using views and the db as a proxy for the middleware a solution that crossed my mind and I'm glad that you also think that it is doable. There are pros and cons. For the pro side; it's ADO agnostic and easy enough to implement. On the con side; there will still be a database and I'd prefer to get away from that if possible.

Comment: If you don't own the applications there is little you can do. I would suggest using the Sql Profiler to pull out a log of queries executed.